# Extract Dynamics 365 read audit log data from security compliance center

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365-sales

I want to extract the read audit data from Microsoft security & compliance center and I have enable the audit logs for read audit logs and now I need to extract from Microsoft security & compliance center and I see the audit log created in Microsoft security & compliance center. Now I want extract or export data from Microsoft security & compliance center to Azure event hub using console app or web api.

Can anyone help me, how can I extract the data from Microsoft security & compliance center I used XRMToolBox using audit history extractor and it is extracting the audit data from CRM but I need extract or export the read audit data for Dynamics CRM from Microsoft security & compliance center.

How can I build the process? I checked my website I don't see any proper resource.

Answer (score 1):

It’s little bit tricky and not so straight forward. You can get a webhook trigger for new data once ready, then you need to parse it and send to your event hub.

[Office 365 Management Activity API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference)

> The Office 365 Management Activity API aggregates actions and events into tenant-specific content blobs, which are classified by the type and source of the content they contain.

> To begin retrieving content blobs for a tenant, you first a create subscription to the desired content types. If you are retrieving content blobs for multiple tenants, you create multiple subscriptions to each of the desired content types, one for each tenant.

> After you create a subscription, you can poll regularly to discover new content blobs that are available for download, or you can register a webhook endpoint with the subscription and we will send notifications to this endpoint as new content blobs are available.

> Note:
> When a subscription is created, it can take up to 12 hours for the first content blobs to become available for that subscription. The content blobs are created by collecting and aggregating actions and events across multiple servers and datacenters. As a result of this distributed process, the actions and events contained in the content blobs will not necessarily appear in the order in which they occurred. One content blob can contain actions and events that occurred prior to the actions and events contained in an earlier content blob. We are working to decrease the latency between the occurrence of actions and events and their availability within a content blob, but we can't guarantee that they appear sequentially.

[Sample logs and schema reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/enable-use-comprehensive-auditing)

Comment: Sorry for the off - you are the only user having both the "Not a Robot" and "Research Assistant" badges. All the other badge pairs were earned by at least two people. ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1354931/rarest-but-existing-badge-pairs#resultSets))

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica: that’s interesting, thank you